# Parts of div border being cut off

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a container element that is holding a few other elements, but depending on the screen size parts of them are inexplicably cut off at various portions. You can observe the behaviour on my code sandbox link, when the HTML page is adjusted in width (by clicking and dragging it). How can I ensure that only the main container border is rendered, and that the child elements do not have any impact?

[image: border]

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-tree-ms4f2

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledTextBox = styled.div`
  height: 15vh;
  width: 30vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  > * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
`;

const InputBox = styled.span`
  height: 35%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
`;



const UserInput = styled.input`
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
`;

const SolutionBox = styled.div`
  height: 35%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
`;

const StyledKeyboard = styled.span`
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
`

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyledTextBox>
      <InputBox>
        <UserInput />
      </InputBox>
      <SolutionBox/>
      <StyledKeyboard/>
    </StyledTextBox>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Perplexityy, can you provide a screenshot, please? I don't seem to be able to reproduce or Im not fully understanding the problem from the post.

Comment: I added an image. The problem I'm having is that the container elements are interfering with the outside border. I would like it to be a consistently solid render regardless of what I put in it.

Comment: The code in the sandbox is different from the one you posted here, and neither versions exhibit the behavior in the image (checked both Chrome and Firefox resizing the window).

Comment: Sorry, I updated the sandbox. And that is very strange, I continue to get the same problems.

Comment: I can't reproduce. What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: Your StyledTextBox component is holding only the UserInput component as I can see in the sandbox. Also, if you color the UserInput component so you can see it, it seems nothing is cut off, everything Is working fine.

Comment: Same here I've added some colors to the components to see better. Is this https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-ellis-k7ywy what you need?

Comment: In addition to OS and browser, what is your screen resolution?  If on a mac, do you have a retina display?  LCD font smoothing used to cause things like this too but I think that's a thing of the past now...?

Comment: @awran5 yes, and on my browser/OS the thickness of the border is being reduced slightly at different parts. is that not the same for you? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: i am using Windows 10 on Google Chrome

Comment: It's very funny, you asked a question and leave a CodeSandBox for it, but when I see your CodeSandBox link, it is so different from your question codes and results.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Can you try to provide a gif? You might want to update your CodeSandbox's code because it is currently not the same as the code you posted here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the other commenters, I can quite make out the error you are reporting, but it sounded to me like a `box-sizing` issue. When reviewing the rendered DOM via https://k7ywy.codesandbox.io/ we can see `box-sizing:border-box` is not being applied to the wrapper element or the internal elements, but it is fixed in the snippet you pasted in the question.

I noticed a few things I'd question.

1. Why not apply `box-sizing` to everything? Usually when dealing with `width:100%;` and `padding`/`border`/`margin`, it makes life so much easier!
   In my example I removed it from the JS and applied it using the CSS file.
2. Why are you using `display:flex` in multiple places but not assinging any other flex-related properties?
   Try removing that from `const InputBox = styled.span` and `const StyledKeyboard = styled.span`

Does that fix it for you? [Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-glade-f7ngs). [Rendered output](https://f7ngs.codesandbox.io/).

Comment: In your screenshot, the right border is noticeably thinner than say, the bottom border.

Comment: I leave and upvote to your post, I hope you will get the bounty at least the half of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply background none or transparent to input field and this will resolve border issue

```
.muXee{
    background-color: transparent;
//OR background:none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a box-sizing issue. You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp). I also recommend you don't use `display: flex`. Maybe try changing the background color to transparent? Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A nice easy way is to give `box-sizing: border-box` to the parent element. To be safe, you can do this at the root component level:

```
* {
  ...;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```